# How to call unit test case for the C# library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I am making a n tier architecture program - which has

BAL - Business access logic library,
DAL - Data access logic - library,
Settings - a library,
and the Main Application - executable - asp.net web form.

Now, I have written a unit test case to test the settings library - this library does nothing but reads the connection string from the main application `web.config`.

When I invoke test case, the connection string isn't read. What am I doing wrong here.

web.config from the executable project -

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- DataSource is SQLEXPRESS and Catalog is DBNAME-->
    <add name="SqlCon" connectionString="Data Source=SHREYAS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SchoolManagementDb;Integrated Security=true"/>  
</connectionStrings>
```

settings library --

```
namespace Settings
{
    public class Settings
    {
        public static string ConnectionString()
        {
            try
            {
                string Con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlCon"].ToString();
                return Con;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The unit test case --

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTestSettings
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string con = Settings.Settings.ConnectionString();
        Console.WriteLine(con);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I am running the unit-test case, the connectionString return is NULL, whereas if I run the entire application I get the results I desire.
Am I missing any concept here?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is in the web project, not your test project.

Add a connection string/ app setting to your test project app.config to test that you can read it correctly.

Comment: then how can I test this?

Comment: Or you can overload your settings reader to allow you to pass a reference to an external config or settings object.

Comment: The functionality of your Settings class is to read configuration values from the config file. And your unit tests verifies that functionality. Using unit test you can not read the settings from web.config. So you need to add app.config in the test project and put connection string over there. When you run the unit test it should be able to read the value from the app.config of test project. That's how to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration is read from the `.config` file of the startup application or site, which in the case of the unit test is the `app.config` of the test project. Move the connection string there.

That aside the test case should also be updated.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTestSettings {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = "Place expected connection string here"
        //Act
        var actual = Settings.Settings.ConnectionString();
        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

In addition to the above I would suggest refactoring the architecture to use abstraction and avoid coupling to static classes/members that make testing difficult. You have already made it follow Single responsibility Principle, which is good. You should make dependents rely on an abstraction rather than on implementation concerns.

For example, abstract the settings (service)

```
public interface ISettings {
    string ConnectionString { get; }
}
```

Here is the implementation.

```
public class Settings : ISettings {
    public string ConnectionString {
        get {
            try {
                var value = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlCon"].ToString();
                return value;
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The only thing to add is that you might want to look into MS Fakes (if you have VS enterprise) in which case you can skip the annoying .config file altogether.